# SSIS VS17 Unsupported: This version of visual studio is unable to open the following projects dtproj

Tags: ssis

I get this error when trying to open **VS17** With SSIS Project **written on VS15**:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

These actions solved my problem:

- Install the [latest version of SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017)
- Open Visual Studio 2017: Go to: Tools > Extensions And Updates > Search: Microsoft Integration Services Projects > Click: Enable
- Restart Visual Studio
- In SSIS Project On Solution: Right Click > Reload Project

Answer (score 0):

I encourated the same error, but I have SSDT installed and updated.
I enabled the Microsoft Analysis Services Projects from Tools->> Extensions and Updates 
I restared visual studio and teh issue was relsolved .
[image]